# Why does my initWithData return nil indicating an error after converting NSData to NSString returning from encrypting via CommonCrypto?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, encryption, commoncrypto

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)encryptText:(id)sender
{
key = self.tvKey.text;

CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;                                        
algorithm = kCCAlgorithmAES128;                                                
CCOptions opts = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;

NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *plainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.tvEntryText.text];
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *encryptedData = [plainData dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: algorithm     
                                                           key: keyData       
                                          initializationVector: nil             
                                                       options: opts           
                                                         error: &status];    


if ( status != kCCSuccess ) {
    NSError * err = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];
    self.lblKeyMsg.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encryption failed: %s", [[err localizedDescription] UTF8String]];
    self.lblKeyMsg.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return;
}

NSString *encryptedString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
self.tvResultText.text = encryptedString;
```

}

The second to last statement I am converting the encrypted NSData to an NSString for display purposes, but it comes back nil. Nil is a valid response indicating and error. I have stopped the execution right after that statement has run and here are the vaues:

```
(gdb) po keyData
<61616161 61616161 61617373 73737373 73737373 64646464 64646464 64646666>
(gdb) po key
aaaaaaaaaassssssssssddddddddddff
(gdb) po plainString
this is a test.
(gdb) po plainData
<74686973 20697320 61207465 73742e>
(gdb) po encryptedData
<f7074146 b295e340 0d947d53 9ea629cf>
(gdb) po encryptedString
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) po status
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb)
```

The status is nil indicating that there was NO error in the encryption. All values appear to be as expected, but the initWithData fails. Here is the operations iPhone view:

[image: The app screen when Encrypt button is pressed]

Why is the initWithData failing here ?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that those bytes are valid utf8 data

Comment: Fredrick, why ? What code present there would be responsible for what you allude to ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation says, `initWithData:encoding:` may return nil if the data passed is not valid data for the encoding. Unlike some encodings, you can't just take arbitrary data and pretend it's UTF8 data - it has to conform to the UTF8 specification.

Your `encryptedData` NSData object will contain seemingly random data - highly unlikely to be valid utf8 data and so `initWithData:encoding:` is very likely to fail.

If you're just looking for something that you can stick in a text box, you might want to try base64 encoding the encrypted data.